# SoapUI property transfer converting value to float when trying to add an integer

Tags: xml, xpath, soapui

I have a property transfer set up in one of my test cases and what I am trying to do is get a value from a response as xml and add 1 to that value and then transfer it to a customer property for that test case.

In the source section I have:

```
//user_school_id
```

This transfers the following value:

> 52

However when I use the following:

```
//user_school_id + 1
```

It transfers:

> 53.0

This breaks the downstream test steps as they are expecting an integer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the string representation of the sum, such as:

```
string(//user_school_id + 1)
```

This will transfer the literal value.